# WebDAV Ubuntu Server y Cliente - No puedo crear, ni editar archivos

Tags: apache2, ubuntu-server

Desde el FileManager de *Ubuntu Desktop 20.04*, conectado a un serivicio **WebDAV** en *Ubuntu server 22.04*, No puedo editar los archivos de texto, ni arrastrar y soltar archivos para crearlos.
No obstante, Si puedo duplicar el archivo, crear carpetas y mover archivos ya creados a las carpetas nuevas.

¿Me falta algo en la configuración?

El Cliente se conecta con `dav://10.0.2.21/minube`, y se ve perfectamente desde el FileManager.

En el servidor `$ cat sites-available/000-default.conf` muestra la configuración mínima:

```
DavLockDB /var/www/DavLock
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        Alias /minube /var/www/html/webdav
        <Location /minube>
          Dav On
          Require all granted
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Los permisos de los directporios están (creo) bien:

```
$ ll /var/
...
drwxrwxr-x  3 www-data www-data 4096 Jan 11 18:09 www/
$ ll /var/www/DavLock
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data 12288 Jan 11 16:24 /var/www/DavLock*
```

y en el directorio del serviciop web y webdav los permisos están forzados

```
$ sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/
$ sudo chmod a+w -R /var/html/
```

¿Alguien puede darme una pista?
Gracias

Comment: Hola veo que estas teniendo dificultades para la configuracion de un software lamentablemente en sitio no vemos este tiepo de situaciones, te recomendaria visitar y exponer el problema en el sitio https://superuser.com/

Comment: en donde te podran dar una mejor orientacion. saludos.